# How to convert xml with 2 similar child in one row in different row in csv using php

Tags: php, xml, csv

I have xml name shipped.xml from ebay Order API, I am having challenge converting it rightly to csv. For example, there will be a time that we will have order where a buyer combine two or more items. usually they will be in the same `<Order>` Row.

My Challenge is how to put the items into separate rows. The `<TransactionID>` and `<SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber>` are usually different for each item, How can I make the csv to go per `<TransactionID>` Or `<SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber>`.

Here is the xml sample

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetOrdersResponse
    xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2016-05-21T09:07:54.497Z</Timestamp>
    <PaginationResult>
        <TotalNumberOfPages>1</TotalNumberOfPages>
        <TotalNumberOfEntries>94</TotalNumberOfEntries>
    </PaginationResult>
    <OrderArray>
        <Order>
            <OrderID>20934xxxxxxx</OrderID>
            <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
            <CheckoutStatus>
                <Status>Complete</Status>
                <IntegratedMerchantCreditCardEnabled>false</IntegratedMerchantCreditCardEnabled>
            </CheckoutStatus>
            <ShippingDetails>
                <SalesTax>
                    <SalesTaxPercent>0.0</SalesTaxPercent>
                    <SalesTaxState></SalesTaxState>
                    <ShippingIncludedInTax>false</ShippingIncludedInTax>
                    <SalesTaxAmount currencyID="USD">0.0</SalesTaxAmount>
                </SalesTax>
                <ShippingServiceOptions>
                    <ShippingService>USPSFirstClass</ShippingService>
                    <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceCost>
                    <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
                    <ExpeditedService>false</ExpeditedService>
                    <ShippingTimeMin>2</ShippingTimeMin>
                    <ShippingTimeMax>6</ShippingTimeMax>
                </ShippingServiceOptions>
                <SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber>15003</SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber>
                <GetItFast>false</GetItFast>
            </ShippingDetails>
            <CreatingUserRole>Buyer</CreatingUserRole>
            <CreatedTime>2016-05-20T15:49:56.000Z</CreatedTime>
            <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
            <SellerEmail>raaynike@yahoo.com</SellerEmail>
            <ShippingAddress>
                <Name>Ejoy. Wadeld</Name>
                <Street1>1611A S Zion Dr</Street1>
                <Street2># 134</Street2>
                <CityName>Vista</CityName>
                <StateOrProvince>CA</StateOrProvince>
                <Country>US</Country>
                <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
                <Phone>760 453 xxxx</Phone>
                <PostalCode>92081-5471</PostalCode>
                <AddressID>1488500000000</AddressID>
                <AddressOwner>eBay</AddressOwner>
                <ExternalAddressID></ExternalAddressID>
            </ShippingAddress>
            <ShippingServiceSelected>
                <ShippingService>USPSFirstClass</ShippingService>
                <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceCost>
            </ShippingServiceSelected>
            <Subtotal currencyID="USD">420.41</Subtotal>
            <Total currencyID="USD">420.41</Total>
            <ExternalTransaction>
                <ExternalTransactionID>0EF4715xxxxxxx</ExternalTransactionID>
                <ExternalTransactionTime>2016-05-20T15:49:56.000Z</ExternalTransactionTime>
                <FeeOrCreditAmount currencyID="USD">1.23</FeeOrCreditAmount>
                <PaymentOrRefundAmount currencyID="USD">42.41</PaymentOrRefundAmount>
            </ExternalTransaction>
            <TransactionArray>
                <Transaction>
                    <Buyer>
                        <Email>manraysxxx@hotmail.com</Email>
                        <UserFirstName></UserFirstName>
                        <UserLastName></UserLastName>
                    </Buyer>
                    <ShippingDetails>
                        <SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber>15001</SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber>
                    </ShippingDetails>
                    <CreatedDate>2016-05-20T15:49:56.000Z</CreatedDate>
                    <Item>
                        <ItemID>252285900000</ItemID>
                        <Site>US</Site>
                        <Title>Eternity Men By Calvin Klein- Etd Spray 3.4 Oz (Unboxed)</Title>
                        <SKU>xxxx-2099</SKU>
                        <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
                        <ConditionDisplayName>New</ConditionDisplayName>
                    </Item>
                    <QuantityPurchased>1</QuantityPurchased>
                    <Status>
                        <PaymentHoldStatus>None</PaymentHoldStatus>
                    </Status>
                    <TransactionID>1853810111111</TransactionID>
                    <TransactionPrice currencyID="USD">20.89</TransactionPrice>
                    <TransactionSiteID>US</TransactionSiteID>
                    <Platform>eBay</Platform>
                    <Taxes>
                        <TotalTaxAmount currencyID="USD">0.0</TotalTaxAmount>
                        <TaxDetails>
                            <Imposition>SalesTax</Imposition>
                            <TaxDescription>SalesTax</TaxDescription>
                            <TaxAmount currencyID="USD">0.0</TaxAmount>
                            <TaxOnSubtotalAmount currencyID="USD">0.0</TaxOnSubtotalAmount>
                            <TaxOnShippingAmount currencyID="USD">0.0</TaxOnShippingAmount>
                            <TaxOnHandlingAmount currencyID="USD">0.0</TaxOnHandlingAmount>
                        </TaxDetails>
                        <TaxDetails>
                            <Imposition>WasteRecyclingFee</Imposition>
                            <TaxDescription>ElectronicWasteRecyclingFee</TaxDescription>
                            <TaxAmount currencyID="USD">0.0</TaxAmount>
                        </TaxDetails>
                    </Taxes>
                    <ActualShippingCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ActualShippingCost>
                    <ActualHandlingCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ActualHandlingCost>
                    <OrderLineItemID>252285900000-1853810111111</OrderLineItemID>
                </Transaction>
                <Transaction>
                    <Buyer>
                        <Email>manraysxxxx@hotmail.com</Email>
                        <UserFirstName></UserFirstName>
                        <UserLastName></UserLastName>
                    </Buyer>
                    <ShippingDetails>
                        <SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber>15002</SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber>
                    </ShippingDetails>
                    <CreatedDate>2016-05-20T15:49:56.000Z</CreatedDate>
                    <Item>
                        <ItemID>351694900000</ItemID>
                        <Site>US</Site>
                        <Title>Love And Luck Men By Ed Hardy - Etd Spray 1.7 OZ</Title>
                        <SKU>xxxx-4702</SKU>
                        <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
                        <ConditionDisplayName>New</ConditionDisplayName>
                    </Item>
                    <QuantityPurchased>1</QuantityPurchased>
                    <Status>
                        <PaymentHoldStatus>None</PaymentHoldStatus>
                    </Status>
                    <TransactionID>800279444444</TransactionID>
                    <TransactionPrice currencyID="USD">210.52</TransactionPrice>
                    <TransactionSiteID>US</TransactionSiteID>
                    <Platform>eBay</Platform>
                    <ActualShippingCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ActualShippingCost>
                    <ActualHandlingCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ActualHandlingCost>
                    <OrderLineItemID>351694900000-800279444444</OrderLineItemID>
                </Transaction>
            </TransactionArray>
            <BuyerUserID>man-shopxyz</BuyerUserID>
            <PaidTime>2016-05-20T15:49:57.000Z</PaidTime>
            <IntegratedMerchantCreditCardEnabled>false</IntegratedMerchantCreditCardEnabled>
            <MonetaryDetails>
                <Payments>
                    <Payment>
                        <PaymentStatus>Succeeded</PaymentStatus>
                        <Payer type="eBayUser">man-shopxyz</Payer>
                        <Payee type="eBayUser">perfumeFx</Payee>
                        <PaymentTime>2016-05-20T15:49:56.000Z</PaymentTime>
                        <PaymentAmount currencyID="USD">42.41</PaymentAmount>
                        <ReferenceID type="ExternalTransactionID">0EF471563vvvvvvvv</ReferenceID>
                        <FeeOrCreditAmount currencyID="USD">1.23</FeeOrCreditAmount>
                    </Payment>
                </Payments>
            </MonetaryDetails>
        </Order>
    </OrderArray>
    <OrdersPerPage>100</OrdersPerPage>
    <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
    <ReturnedOrderCountActual>94</ReturnedOrderCountActual>
</GetOrdersResponse>
```

And Here is my script, it works fine on order item order. But not on multiple, please advice me on this

```
$filexml='shipped.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) {
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
  $f = fopen('product.csv', 'w');


$headers = ['Sales Record Number','Sales Record Number2','User Id ','Buyer Fullname ','Buyer Phone Number ','Buyer Email ','Buyer Address 1 ','Buyer Address 2 ','Buyer City ','Buyer State ','Buyer Zip ','Buyer Country ','Order ID ','Item ID ','Transaction ID ','Item Title ','Quantity ','Sale Price ','Shipping And Handling ','Total Price ','Notes to Yourself ','Custom Label','Shipped Time'];

fputcsv($f, $headers);


foreach($xml->OrderArray->Order as $product) {        


if ($product->ShippedTime != ""){

continue;

}

  $values = array(

   "Sales Record Number" => $product->TransactionArray->Transaction->ShippingDetails->SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber,
   "Sales Record Number2" => $product->ShippingDetails->SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber,
"User Id" => $product->BuyerUserID,
"Buyer Fullname" => $product->ShippingAddress->Name,
"Buyer Phone Number" => $product->ShippingAddress->Phone,
"Buyer Email" => $product->TransactionArray->Transaction->Buyer->Email,
"Buyer Address 1" => $product->ShippingAddress->Street1,
"Buyer Address 2" => $product->ShippingAddress->Street2,
"Buyer City" => $product->ShippingAddress->CityName,
"Buyer State" => $product->ShippingAddress->StateOrProvince,
"Buyer Zip" => $product->ShippingAddress->PostalCode,
"Buyer Country" => $product->ShippingAddress->CountryName,
"Order ID" => $product->OrderID,
"Item ID" => $product->TransactionArray->Transaction->Item->ItemID,
"Transaction ID" => $product->TransactionArray->Transaction->TransactionID,
"Item Title" => $product->TransactionArray->Transaction->Item->Title,
"Quantity" => $product->TransactionArray->Transaction->QuantityPurchased,
"Sale Price" => $product->->TransactionArray->Transaction->TransactionPrice,
"Shipping And Handling" => $product->ShippingServiceSelected->ShippingService,
"Total Price" => $product->TransactionArray->Transaction->TransactionPrice,
"Notes to Yourself" => $product->BuyerCheckoutMessage,
"Custom Label" => $product->TransactionArray->Transaction->Item->SKU,
"Shipped Time" => $product->ShippedTime);
   fputcsv($f, $values,',','"');
  }


fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: Is there ever a need to convert XML to CSV?

Comment: @e4c5 yes, I need to convert it to csv file so, we can send it to our vendor  to process the order. Thanks

Comment: Please strip out personal data on this public site!

Comment: Can you properly indent this example. Some sites can help pretty print XML. It is hard to determine tree structure parents/chidren. Does this example have multiple items in an order?

Comment: @Parfait I did remove personal data from the xml, the one there is not any real persons name, email, address or phone number, even user name. Regarding your second question, yes this example has multiple order in it.